# Facebook search by name or email

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am developing a site with facebook connect using javascript Fql query. Is there a way, using javascript fql to search members by name or by email.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can search different objects (groups, posts, events etc.) by providing a keyword. The format is: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=QUERY&type=OBJECT_TYPE

More info in the 'Searching' section here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Note that you can't search by email.

Answer (score 0):

Vikas's suggestion is good for Graph API. If you want FQL for more complex reasons, take a look at [this example](http://www.fbrell.com/hidden/whitepages).

```
SELECT name, pic_square, profile_url FROM user WHERE contains("zuck")
```